# Google maps API v3 : containsLocation() vs. geojson data

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have on my web application a city geographically divided into neighborhoods. I used geojson file described as an array of the following :

```
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [
 {
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "color" : "red",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          2.38317,
          48.867111
        ],
        [
          2.363713,
          48.867554
        ],
        [
          2.364399,
          48.867126
        ],
        [
          2.39839,
          48.85133
        ],
        [
          2.39432,
          48.856541
        ],
        [
          2.39223,
          48.857571
        ],
        [
          2.38965,
          48.85844
        ],
        [
          2.38746,
          48.86282
        ],
        [
          2.38377,
          48.86607
        ],
        [
          2.38317,
          48.867111
        ]
      ]
    ]
  },
  "properties": {
    "id" : "11",
    "name": "11ème : arr",
    "description": "this is 11",
    "arr": "11e"
  }
}, ...
```

My aim is to look where the user's address is located withing my polygons. I get the address from  [HTML5 get my location](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation)or by entering own address in a autocomplete search bar it returns => google.maps.LatLng object.

How is it possibile to explore the drown polygons objects knowing that containsLocation needs LatLng formatted polygons

[Here's the example which uses google.maps.Polygon object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, I've converted all features with this script

https://github.com/JasonSanford/geojson-google-maps/blob/master/GeoJSON.js